# Painting in AndEngine Android

Tags: android, andengine

I want to know that are there any painting tools in AndEngine?
Or any one has any idea how can I paint the scene on Touch with Different Colors??

If you have used Paint or Photo shop there is a painting option in it.
I want to have the same functionality in my app.I am working on a coloring app for kids. Using Line in AndEngine for this purpose with not give smoothness and quality. Do you have any idea that how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a sprite (white circle). And add it every time when user touches the screen (in `onAreaTouched()` method). If `MotionEvent == ACTION_DOWN` or `MotionEvent == ACTION_MOVE` just add a sprite.

You can use `sprite.setColor()` to change brush color and `sprite.setScale()` to change your brush size.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by LayoutGamActivity. Use layoutgameActivity and add customize View in XMl.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Entity "Line" which can be painted and have a defined "width". Maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Then, can you please improve your question?

Comment: Yeah sure I have done it. The question is now more descriptive.